# Excel 2013 giving different answer for the same value and formula in different cell

Tags: javascript, excel

I use a sample calculator in the excel to create a new one using JavaScript. when i calculating the **Cost(dirty)** the answers i got is different from the answer.  in the excel. So i tried in these in excel

- First i use the cell for the calculations it give the same answer as in the excel (EG:=C13/100*C20). i got 960,918.00
- Then i tried the values it gives different answer but same as i get from the JavaScript (EG: =96.09*(1000000/100)). i got 960900.

Excel calculations
Last coupon date: =COUPPCD(C2,C4,2,1)
Next coupon date: =COUPNCD(C2,C4,2,1)
Clean price: =ROUND((PRICE(C2,C4,C5,C7,100,2,1)),4)
Accrued interest: =ROUND(ACCRINT(C9,C11,C2,C5,100,2,1),4)
Dirty Price: =C15+C18
Cost(dirty): =C13/100*C20

I am unable to include a screenshot so i mention like this

> C2: 24-Aug-2008, C4: 01-Apr-2018, C5: 16.00%, C7: 18.29%, C9:Last coupon date. C11: Next coupon date, C13: 1000000, C15: Clean price, C18: Accrued interest, C20: Dirty Price, C23: Cost(dirty).

Please help me, i don't know why the two answers are different

FYI: I tried whether the value in the C20 and 96.09 are same, i get FALSE as result and they don't have any different also.

I really confused with this and i get stuck please give some solutions if you can.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - you are having `96.0918` in your cell C20 which is derived using  `=C15+C18 (DirtyPrice)` And you are comparing it with 96.09 (using JS).

If you want to have the same result as your JS/calculator then you need to round it like `=ROUND(C15+C18,2)`

If you are seeing 96.09 in your cell C20 then just format it to have General formatting or to have 4 decimal places. You can do that by right click on cell and select Format Cells option.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks its worked. Round function help to change in the excel, but is there any way to do same as in the excel answer in javascript